# Using WS_EX_CONTEXTHELP with the WS_MAXIMIZEBOX or WS_MINIMIZEBOX styles

Tags: mfc

I see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff700543(v=vs.85).aspx) that it says:

> **`WS_EX_CONTEXTHELP`**
>
> `WS_EX_CONTEXTHELP` cannot be used with the `WS_MAXIMIZEBOX` or `WS_MINIMIZEBOX` styles.

Is this still the case? I would like to have this icon too. The reason I ask is because when using Windows Blinds I get these:

[image: Title Bar]

So it has:

- Collapse to just the title bar (don't know the official term - it is a Windows Blinds thing).
- Minimize
- Maximize / Restore
- Close

So it has an extra icon anyway. But I can't get it to show the context help icon too. Is there any new way to do it?

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33799055/why-i-dont-see-a-question-mark-when-i-use-ws-ex-contexthelp) so I guess the immidiate answer is no. But if Windows Blinds can add a extra button .... ?

Comment: No, the help icon will not appear when min/max is visible. You can have up to 3 icons: [minimize], [maximize/restore], [close]

Comment: So I would have to add my own little icon in a corner of the window for them to click.

Comment: That's right. You can just add a Help button, or help icon button somewhere in client area, it will be more visible.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani Pity, I was hoping to use https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/6243atkt(v=vs.85) (`LoadOEMBitmap`) to load the context help icon into some control. There is no constant for it. I already have the help button though.